# What do we call the gesture of hitting each other's fists gently?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

We all know shaking hands or a handshake. There, we 'shake hands'.

There's one more gesture I do. I gently *punch* other's fist.

Something like this -

[image: courtesy -dreamstime.com]

What do we call this gesture as *a noun*?

> They close the deal with *a handshake*
>
> The close the deal with *(a?)* ____________

Also, as *a verb?*

> Whenever we meet, we *shake hands*
>
> Whenever we meet, we ___________

If there's no single word, a couple would do.

Comment: it's called bro fist

Comment: I know it's hypothetical, but I don't think anyone would close a deal with a fist bump. That's just not formal. *Whenever we meet, we do a fist bump.*

Comment: @Usernew Maybe if it was a drug deal...

Comment: @BriceM.Dempsey That paints a *hilarious* mental picture. "You got the goods?" "Yeah man, pound it."

Comment: @Usernew there could be *many such deals*. You do me a favor...I do you the same... deal? First Bump!

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, but it's not formal. It's not something you would see happening to finalise a deal.

Comment: Don't think that you always meet *serious* people! @Usernew At least, I'm lucky in that case!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *Don't think that you always meet serious people!* If you are saying that serious people do close a deal with a fistbump, then, probably, you are living in a different world. :) Yes, you might fist bump with your colleagues as a "hello" or "goodbye," but closing a deal with a fist bump? That's absurd. @MaulikV

Comment: You are stretching too much on the word *deal!* Better we focus on the naming *gesture.* Anyway, *first bump* is what I was looking for. :) @Usernew And, BTW, I said *serious people 
**don't** close deal with a fist bump!

Comment: Handshakes don't *really* close important deals, written contacts do. If a particular deal is insignificant enough that a handshake alone is enough then possibly a fist bump would be an acceptable alternative in some circles.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's called a [**fist bump**](https://www.google.com.hk/search?hl=en&biw=1161&bih=710&tbm=isch&sa=1&btnG=Search&q=fist+bump).

It's also known as [**pound** or **dap**](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/features/will-fist-bumps-replace-the-handshake-9634151.html).

[image]

Comment: that's right...though I'll wait for others to answer!

Comment: aka [terrorist fist jab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_vmQrTi3aM)

Answer (score 9):

I agree with the dominant answer, but to be a tad more pedantic:

We call this gesture, as a noun:

> They close the deal with a *handshake*.
>
> The close the deal with **a fist-bump**.

As a verb:

> Whenever we meet, we *shake hands*.
>
> Whenever we meet, we **bump fists**.

QED.

ps: A fist-bump is demonstrably cleaner than a handshake, [epidemiologically](http://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2014/07/29/336272173/fist-bumps-pass-along-fewer-germs-than-handshakes).

Comment: I would find it perfectly acceptable to use "fist-bump" as a verb. `Whenever we meet, we fist bump`.

Comment: And just to be pedantic to a pedant, `QED` - `Quod erat demonstrandum` is used after a formal proof, not after an example.

Comment: @JamesWebster Of course, but the topic was a bit silly, so I used QED in a silly manner. :)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the more formal "fist bump", a more slang term is [brofist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fist_bump). this term is quite popular online, to the point that major Youtube celebrity Pewdiepie made it part of the title of his videogame.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Pewdiepie. It is also quite often heard and seen in TV serials.

Comment: I think the term is only popular *because* of Pewdiepie, because it only got big within the last year.  [Overall, "fist bump" is still the clear leader.](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?hl=en-US&q=fist+bump,+bro+fist,+brofist&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT%2B4&tz=Etc/GMT%2B4&content=1)  (Actually, "dap" might be even more common, but  it's hard to search for, since it has a lot of other meanings too.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm a native speaker in my 20's and I have never heard "brofist" or "dap". There might be specific subcultures or regions where these terms are more prevalent or less prevalent.

Comment: "Brofist" may be a more online term; it's definitely very young. "Dap" is better known in African American communities, dates back to the 1970s, and encompasses options more complex than the fist bump. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giving_dap

Comment: Fist-bump was popular long before Pewdiepie, generally as a form of congratulations. A handshake is more appropriate for closing a deal.

Comment: I don't think Pewdiepie invented the term brofist; I've been using it for over a decade, though maybe that was a regional expression until he exposed it to more people.

Comment: 'Dap' is how I knew it growing up (Dallas, Texas, went to a middle school with a large African American population).  Fist-bump is a good generic term that most anybody should understand.  However, if you're saying "Bro?" or "Bro." when you do it, it's definitely a brofist.  Lastly, if you're a Fox News anchor you might call it a Terrorist Fist-Jab.

Comment: What is a Pewdiepie and how do you pronounce it?

Comment: @shoover Pewdiepie is the biggest Youtube celebrity of this moment, with over 43 million subscribers and counting; pew and pie are pronounced as the English words, die is pronounced in a German style.

Comment: At least where I live (Germany, big city) brofist is quite well-known for 3yrs or so. Also a maybe not-so-well-established source, yet still interesting: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/bro-fist

Answer (score 1):

If your business is with a male fan of My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic, then it is customary to seal the deal with a "brohoof" - again, this is just for brony business.

[Urban Dictionary:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=brohoof)

> brohoof: *Friendly gesture between one brony and another in the form of connecting knuckles together (or hoofs).*

Comment: +1 thanks for sharing this. Quite new to me. I added the reference to improve it.

Comment: This is true, but I'm not sure this is so much a different term as it is just an adapted version of "brofist". Both the fandom and characters in the TV show itself often substitute human-centric terms for words more suited to ponies. (E,g, "clap your hands" -> "clop your hooves", "everybody" -> "everypony", etc)  "Hoof bump" would also be acceptable here, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> They closed the deal with a handshake. 
>   The closed the deal with (a) **fistbump**.
>
> Whenever we meet, we shake hands. 
>   Whenever we meet, we **fistbump**.

This is a really informal gesture, so I don't think it could be used to close deals. Since it's informal, I don't think there's any proper conjugation for it either, but it would probably follow the conjugation of the word *bump*.