# "She is exhausted. She was/is/had been/has been running." -- Which should I use?

Tags: tense

> She is exhausted. She _____.
>   1. was running
>   2. is running
>   3. had been running
>   4. has been running

I wanted to complete the sentence, so which form should I use?

Comment: Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Comment: ***5. all of the above.*** There is no context and one can be exhausted while running, directly after running, a while after running or even a longer time after running. [We have a great post about tenses.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: A teacher might well want the answer (4), which would very probably be the most expected answer. But 'Which form should I use?' is rather like asking 'Should I use a saw or bolt crops?'

Comment: @Helmar Including 3 in all of the above is a stretch. Past perfect progressive requires another past event/tense to make sense and "is exhausted" is present

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because 1) it's a request for a homework answer without showing any effort to find the answer or tell us what specifically you're uncertain about; and 2) because arguably all of those answers could be correct

Answer (score 3):

It's quite clear that your question is from an exercise in a grammar book or something similar. (And thus, the context is the exercise.)

Hence, the expected answer would be (4) ***has been running***.

The following entry in *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan should make this point clear:

> **458.6 actions and situations that have just stopped**
>   We also use the present perfect progressive for actions and situations which have just stopped, but which have present results.
>   ​　　　*You look hot. ~ Yes, **I've been running***.
>   ​　　　*Sorry I'm late. **Have** you **been waiting** long?*
>   ​　　　*I must just go and wash. **I've been gardening**.*

---

<sub>Also note that *has been running* is likely the expected answer because the exercise includes the first sentence: *She is exhausted*, which is in the simple present (the verb is *be*; and *exhausted* is an adjective), and is a hint that the exercise expects you to relate the two sentences. (So, it's like *"She's exhausted. Why is she exhausted?" "Because she has been running."*) Keep in mind that in real speech, it's not impossible that a native speaker may use other choices (e.g., *She's exhausted. She was running.*) as you can see in several comments here. -- Another important point, as @Mari-Lou A mentioned in her comment under this answer, is that if the first sentence were in the simple past (i.e., *She was running*), shifting the tense of *has* to *had* would have been more appropriate, and *She had been running* would have been a better answer.</sub>

Comment: I think you should emphasise that the first sentence contains a present simple verb *is*, hence any action that preceded this end result (is exhausted) must have occurred *recently* in the past. If the example had been: *She* **was** *exhausted. ...* number 3 would be the correct answer.

Comment: I agree that the context is the exercise  but you've arbitrarily chosen an exercise. Any of the  four could be the exercise

Comment: @AlanCarmack My personal opinion toward this kind of exercise is perhaps unlike one by most learners: it doesn't necessarily reflect real English. It usually promotes the most probable choice as the correct usage, and sometimes it goes so far as to mark possible but less likely/frequently used alternatives as incorrect. When it comes to context, it usually assumes, again, the most probable scenario. I can see one advantage of this: it helps learners learn the more commonly used phrases and alternatives. This doesn't mean that it's perfect. It's just that it is usually how it is in exercises.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for mentioning that point. I added a note to my answer to cover that point.

Comment: Good edit, but I already upvoted your post, so we have to make do with a [fist bump](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87416/what-do-we-call-the-gesture-of-hitting-each-others-fists-gently). :)